# Which car should we rent to visit several European countries?

Tags: europe, car-rentals, road-trips

We are planning a road trip from Darmstadt - Milan - Pisa - venice - pula - Vienna - Budapest - Bratsilava - Prague - Darmstadt.

Countries covered are: Germany, Switzerland, Italy, Croatia, Austria, Hungary and Czech.

I hope we will not be carrying much of luggage and staying at hostels in between. Trip will start probably from 29th of march and end on 12th April. (Around 14 days)

We are planning to rent a car from Sixt or similar car hiring services.

Which car will be comfortable and economical for 4-5 people?
 Considering weather and road conditions in this route.

Will there be any other problem such as Gas station is not available for a long distance etc.. in this route?

Any help regarding the same is appreciated.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing to worry about. Every car will do.

Comment: All of this is on a highway inside the EU. Can you even do a six hour drive on any EU highway without seeing a gas station? I sincerely doubt! I didn't dig up EU highway codes but I'd bet such a thing is out of regulations. Even for [CNG](http://www.erdgas-mobil.de/cng-as-fuel/available/), the European Commission is pushing for a network of stations with a max 150km distance.

Comment: The only issue would be to fit 5 people in the car, so just don't take the smallest, all the rest is good.

Comment: I've flagged this, as I feel it is a shopping suggestion question, as well as a "what is the best x to buy" question, and both are off-topic. Note I did not downvote, nor will I. If you feel it is on-topic, please don't flame me, just answer the questions asked.

Comment: In any case, no matter what car you get, make sure that the "Vignette" for Switzerland and the "Pickerl" for Austria (both are toll stickers for highways) are provided, or you have the guarantee to be reimbursed if you have to buy them. The "Vignette" for Switzerland has to be stuck to the car, and can not be removed, and the fee is paid until the end of the year; you don't want to sponsor the car renter, don't you…

Comment: @pnuts Nearly every European country has automobile producers and the big countries have several of them. Even before Schengen cars were freely available in other countries. Each producer has several models in several categories changing after some years. So, yes, the question is *much* too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crucial point here is to fit 4-5 people, and their luggage, in a car comfortable enough when driving for long stretches. To this purpose any comfortable station wagon, or even a people carrier if you can manage operating it in narrow driving scenarios such as parking in city centres, will do. To help you choose, car renting websites often specify the comfort of a car in terms of the number of people and luggage they can fit.

Regarding weather conditions keep in mind that local regulations might require you to fit your car with winter equipment - tyres or snow chains - which is mandatory during the months you will be travelling. [This is clearly the case for Italy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/38718/22140), for example. There are a number of questions (see [this one](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/39856/22140) for example) on TSE detailing this, have a nice read.